# Require character anywhere in a match

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working on a regex to match `F. Supp.` or `F.3d` but not `On June` or `foobar`.

So far, I have `[A-Z][ ]?[A-Z|a-z|\.| ][A-Z|a-z|\.| |0-9]+`. It's almost there, but it still matches `On June`. I want to require a `.` (period character), but I want to allow it to be anywhere in the match.

I think I need to use a positive lookahead, but my attempt doesn't work: `(?=[.])[A-Z][ ]?[A-Z|a-z|\.| ][A-Z|a-z|\.| |0-9]+`.

I'm using Python.

Comment: Its worth pointing out that the "So far, I have..." regex could be simplified to `r"[A-Z] ?[A-z\. ][0-z\. ]+"` without any change in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your string contain `.` you can use `in` operand :

```
if '.' in word
```

And with regex you can use a positive look-around to ensure that you have a dot `.` in your string :

```
([\w ]+)?(?=\.).([\w ]+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xa5jb1TzSsGBkYzH)

Answer (score 1):

To *require* a character, you must provide it in the regex pattern *without any optional quantificators like `*` or `?`*. You regex pattern is a bit misleading, as you specified literal `|` symbols in it.

[image]

Try using the `[A-Z] ?\.(?i)[a-z. 0-9]+` regex pattern.

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/cG3cJ9/3)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([A-Z] ?\.(?i)[a-z. 0-9]+)')
test_str = u"F. Supp.\nF.3d\nOn June\nfoobar"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
[A-z| |\d]*\.[A-z| |\d|\.]*
```